# how to add inflate view programmatically in linearlayout with equal width Android

Tags: android-studio, layout-inflater

I need to add inflate layout programmatically in LinearLayout, but widht not divide equally in layout.here i attached output screen. Please help me to solve.

following is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/hsv_category_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_placeHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and following are my class:

```java
public class ScrollTest extends Activity {

    HorizontalScrollView hsv_category_list;
    LinearLayout ll_placeHolder;
    View layoutView[];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.scroll_test);
        hsv_category_list = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsv_category_list);
        ll_placeHolder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_placeHolder);
        layoutView = new View[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            layoutView[i] = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.test_scroll_itwm, null);
            layoutView[i].setId(i);

            ll_placeHolder.addView(layoutView[i], new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    100,
                    200));

        }

    }
}
```

[image: Output]